# How to use \newenvironment; why doesn't this code work? How do I fix it?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, exercises, exsheets

I've been trying to find out but my latex skills are too weak to understand what seem like similar problems. When I try this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%#####################
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{oppg}{\begin{tcolorbox}\begin{question}}{\end{question}\end{tcolorbox}}


\begin{oppg}
Exercise text in a box
\end{oppg}

\begin{oppg}
Exercise text in a box
\end{oppg}

\end{document}
```

I get a whole bunch of errors.

I don't understand why this doesn't work.

How can I wrap my exercises in colored boxes?

Thanks!

Comment: The nesting is weird. I believe, you could get this with `tcolorbox` commands too

Comment: I've removed the `memoir` tag as it is not related to `memoir`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to wrap the `question` environment in a `\tcolorboxenvironment` redefinition.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}



\tcolorboxenvironment{question}{colback=yellow}  % 2nd arg is for tcolorbox options. 

\begin{question}
Exercise text in a box
\end{question}


\end{document}
```

**Edit** A little bit more flexible, without `question` being forever now a `tcolorbox`, I made a copy via `\LetLtxMacro`, naming it `\oppg`.

This could be used with `\tcolorboxenvironment` instead of `question` which is still the same environment. However, both environments share the same counter (so far).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\begin{document}

\LetLtxMacro\oppg\question


\tcolorboxenvironment{oppg}{colback=yellow,colframe=red}


\begin{question}%[print=false]
Exercise text in a box
\end{question}

\begin{oppg}[print=false]
Another box
\end{oppg}

\begin{oppg}
Another box
\end{oppg}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll update with another possibility

Comment: This in a way disables `\begin{question}[print=false]` but that's probably not too big a deal in most use cases

Comment: @clemens: I know, that's why I want to provide another solution

Comment: A solution with `exsheets` other than your current solution may not be easy without hacking. Using `exsheets`' hooks (which are intended for stuff like this) probably won't work with `tcolorbox` I suspect...

Comment: @clemens: Apparently, the `\tcolorboxenvironment` command handles argument correctly. But I did not check for any eventuality

Comment: Thanks for this! But I get "float(s) lost" error if I try to have a figure inside the exercise. Do you know a way to work around it?

Comment: @john.abraham You can't have floating objects inside a box. Note that you don't need `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` around `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @egreg So if I want "Figure 1.3.3" inside a box I need to use captions package or something like that?

Comment: @john.abraham Yes, with `\captionof`.

Comment: Doesn’t address the question of how to use `\newenvironment`.

Answer (score 5):

I've just (2015/07/04) sent an update of `exsheets` to CTAN which allows the following (recommended) solution:

```
\SetupExSheets{
  question/pre-hook = \begin{tcolorbox} ,
  question/post-hook = \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

The update should be available in a few days in TeX Live and MiKTeX. If you don't want to wait: the updated version (v0.19) is also available here: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/commits/tag/v0.19

Full example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}[2015/07/04]
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for showing page dimensions

\SetupExSheets{
  question/pre-hook = \begin{tcolorbox} ,
  question/post-hook = \end{tcolorbox} ,
  solution/pre-hook = \begin{tcolorbox} ,
  solution/post-hook = \end{tcolorbox} ,
  no-skip-below ,
  headings = tcolorbox
}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{tcolorbox}{default}{
  join  = { title[r,B]number[l,B](.333em,0pt) } ,
  attach = {
    main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
    main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep+5.5mm,0pt) % depending on the
                                % colorbox the 5.5mm may need adapting
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}{2}
  This is sample question 1.
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
  This is sample solution 1. 
\end{solution}

\begin{question}{1}
  This is sample question 2.
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
  This is sample solution 2. 
\end{solution}

\begin{question}[print=false]
  This is sample question 3 -- not printed.
\end{question}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

BTW: your usage of `\newenvironment` isn't really wrong. However, both `exsheets`' environments and `tcolorbox`' environments are no simple environments. `exsheets` uses `environ` internally and `tcolorbox` puts the contents in a box… This is the main reason `exsheets` offers hooks to place code before and after the questions/solutions.

Comment: +1 for the update! I really struggled to find a way to merge both environments together, but I could not dig to deep into both package systems

Comment: Nice! Thank you for this, this is exactly what I was looking for! :-)