# Why doesn't \newenvironment work as expected with \alignat?

Tags: macros, environments

**Question:** I tried to do this with `\newenvironment`:

```
\newenvironment{derivation}{ \begin{alignat*}{2}
\begin{split} }{ \end{split}
\end{alignat*} }
```

But when I did

```
\begin{derivation}
    I(\mu) &= \dots
\end{derivation}
```

I got the errors `Paragraph ended before \alignat* was complete`, `Missing $ inserted.`, `Missing \endgroup inserted.`, `Display math should end with $$.`, `\begin{alignat*} on input line 405 ended by \end{document}.`

Did I not use the syntax of `\newenvironment` correctly?

**Attempt:** At first I thought it might have been that the `{2}` was causing a mismatch of curly braces, i.e. it looked like the `enddef` variable to `\newenvironment`, but that actually doesn't make sense. Now I am just staring at the screen confused.

This seems possibly related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253519/how-to-use-newenvironment-why-doesnt-this-code-work-how-do-i-fix-it), but the answers to that question don't explain why the proposed solution doesn't work, they just give alternate solutions which do work. I want to know why this doesn't work so I don't try it again.

**Motivation:**
In order to save time when writing equations like this:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \begin{split}
    \frac{I_{\theta}(\theta)}{(h'(\theta))^2} &= \frac{    \frac{1}{ \theta}  }{ \left(  \frac{1}{\theta} \right)^2 } \\
    &= \frac{\theta^2}{ \theta}  = \theta = e^{\eta} = I_{\eta}(\eta) \,. \quad \square
    \end{split}
\end{alignat*}
```

Comment: The issue you describe has come up several times on this site. The root of the problem is that the `alignat*` environment is programmed to scan ahead in the input stream to find the string `\end{alignat*}` before doing most of its work. This scanning-ahead takes place *before* expansion of the directive `\end{derivation}` into `\end{split} \end{alignat*}` occurs. And, because LaTeX doesn't "encounter" `\end{alignat*` before the end of the document is reached, it exits with an error message.

Comment: Why do you use the `split` environment *within* `alignat*`?

Comment: @GuM It gets better spacing around the equals signs.

Comment: the amsmath documentation does explicitly document that you can't do this. `texdoc technote` section 6

Comment: @Chill2Macht I see no difference whatsoever with or without `split`. Of course, `alignat*` does nothing more than `equation*`, in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{derivation}{%
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    \begin{split}
      \BODY
    \end{split}
  \end{alignat*}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{derivation}
  \frac{I_{\theta}(\theta)}{(h'(\theta))^2} &= \frac{\frac{1}{\theta}}{\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right)^2} \\
  &= \frac{\theta^2}{\theta} = \theta = e^{\eta} = I_{\eta}(\eta) \,. \quad \square
\end{derivation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Would be much better formatted as this (in my opinion)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  \begin{align*}
    \frac{I_{\theta}(\theta)}{(h'(\theta))^2}
    &= \frac{1/\theta}{(1/\theta)^2} \\
    &= \frac{\theta^2}{\theta} = \theta = e^{\eta} = I_{\eta}(\eta) \,. \qedhere
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For several reasons you can't define an environment in terms of `split`. Also, defining environments in terms of `align` and similar environments requires using the “internal forms”.

However, in your case, `alignat*` is completely superfluous and could be replaced by `equation*`: after all, `split` cannot take more than one alignment point.

Besides, nesting `split` is useless; there is no difference whatsoever between

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \begin{split}
    \frac{I_{\theta}(\theta)}{(h'(\theta))^2} &= \frac{    \frac{1}{ \theta}  }{ \left(  \frac{1}{\theta} \right)^2 } \\
    &= \frac{\theta^2}{ \theta}  = \theta = e^{\eta} = I_{\eta}(\eta) \,. \quad \square
    \end{split}
\end{alignat*}
```

and

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \frac{I_{\theta}(\theta)}{(h'(\theta))^2} &= \frac{    \frac{1}{ \theta}  }{ \left(  \frac{1}{\theta} \right)^2 } \\
    &= \frac{\theta^2}{ \theta}  = \theta = e^{\eta} = I_{\eta}(\eta) \,. \quad \square
\end{alignat*}
```

What you seem to want is just an alias for `align*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\newenvironment{derivation}
 {\csname align*\endcsname}
 {\endalign}
\makeatletter
\let\derivation@qed\align@qed
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Better using \verb|\qedhere|, though
\begin{derivation}
\frac{I_{\theta}(\theta)}{(h'(\theta))^2}
  &= \frac{\frac{1}{\theta}}{\bigl(\frac{1}{\theta}\bigr)^2} = \frac{1/\theta}{(1/\theta)^2} \\
  &= \frac{\theta^2}{\theta} = \theta = e^{\eta} = I_{\eta}(\eta) \,.\qedhere
\end{derivation}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The square seems to denote an end of proof, but it's much better to use `\qedhere`, in that case.

[image]

I added the slashed form near to the four story fraction: I'd prefer it.